# "technical area" expressed in one word

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

<sup>sorry for my not good english</sup>

I am looking for one word to express the concept of "technical area".

By "technical area" I mean a virtual place (in a web site) where users will find various technical stuff like projects, manuals, drawings, finishes and references about certain products (furnitures).

"technical area" is too long and I am looking for a one word definition (possibly short).

I was looking in various dictionaries but I can't even guess a word since english is not even my mother language.

Comment: If these technical items are arranged by type, order or reference, you may name the area a 'database'. Alternatively, a 'catalogue', although having one connotation of a list of items typically for purchase, may be used to define a list of ordered items.

Comment: How about "resources"?

Answer (score 2):

If 'Technical' is a good descriptor for the content, but you need a short descriptor for a tab, just use 'Technical'. No need to include 'area'; the user will assume 'technical information', 'technical page' or 'technical area' which is fine.

You can then describe it more accurately in the title/page description, e.g. 'Welcome to the Technical Resource Library', etc.

Edit: I don't recommend the word domain, which has a specific meaning in the context of websites. In my opinion, better options are 'library' (if primarily documents), 'database' (if primarily tabular data) or 'resources'/'resource centre' (if they're in mixed formats).

Answer (score 0):

**Domain**  Someone who knows a lot about an area of interest may be called a domain-expert. The domain is their home territory.

Comment: What? I thought that Question had no useful Answer, until I saw Aethelbald's wholly reasonable suggestion. Please, un-downvote that!

Comment: @Robbie,  It is in fact *a* correct answer.  In high-level business systems design, someone has to represent each of the different interested parties.  They are often referred to as domain experts.

Comment: of course they are and would you mind translating that into everyday English, or do you insists it's a specialised realm?

Comment: @Robbie, my response as new answer.  Apologies to all who are shocked, shocked by this transgression and who need to get a life.